# Find and return items based on matching strings across 17 tables

Tags: sql-server, datatypes, pattern-matching

I must start by saying that I am at best a sql novice. I am doing some data analysis and consolidation for my company and need to find if items match across any of the tables. The info in the tables came from 3 different databases and a bunch of spreadsheets that had been used.

The information I'm looking to match up is circuit numbers.  Some of the tables have the same design, but the information is not always entered in the same fields or even the same format. The tables do not have the same number of columns and sometimes the string that would match across them is a sub string in one of the other tables. The id's can be both numeric and alphanumeric. One other issue is that no one single table has enough good/correctly entered data to use as a primary table to compare the rest to.

What I am looking to achieve is to somehow search all of the tables and if there is a string that matches across any number of them, I would like to identify where it matched and create a table that contains the info from all columns in the row(s) that contained the match.

Below is a list of the tables, the number columns each has and the fields in that table that could potentially contain a circuit ID.  I know this is confusing and I hope I was able to explain it and even more hopeful that someone may be able to help since doing a manual stare and compare will take months. I have tried everything that my limited knowledge allows from joins to unions to putting it in excel and using tools like vlookup, but the state of the data is creating too many stumbling blocks for me.  It seems that I may need to use some sort of stored procedure to check through the tables and return the results, but this is something that is quite a bit over my head.

```
Table 1 - 152 columns - CktNum(nvarchar(8)), IXC(nvarchar(25)), BOC(nvarchar(25)), AML(nvarchar(10)), LLOCKTID(nvarchar(25)), assignnum(nvarchar(50))

Table 2 - 17 columns - IXC CKT ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC CKT ID(nvarchar(255)), Local CKTID(nvarchar(255))

Table 3 - 10 columns - Name(nvarchar(255)), Name1(nvarchar(255)), Name2(nvarchar(255))

Table 4 - 21 columns - Local Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), IXC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 5 - 22 columns - Local Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), IXC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 6 - 20 columns - Local Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), IXC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 7 - 20 columns - Local Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), IXC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 8 - 20 columns - Local Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), IXC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), BOC Circuit ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 9 - 5 columns - Local ID(nvarchar(255)), Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), ECCKT ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 10 - 5 columns - Local ID(nvarchar(255)), Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), ECCKT ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 11 - 7 columns - Local ID(nvarchar(255)), Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), ECCKT ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 12 - 5 columns - Local ID(nvarchar(255)), Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), ECCKT ID(nvarchar(255))

Table 13 - 18 columns - Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), Customer(nvarchar(255))

Table 14 - 17 columns - Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), Customer(nvarchar(255))

Table 15 - 40 columns - ECCKT(nvarchar(255)), LO CKT ID(float), CKR(nvarchar(255))

Table 16 - 9 columns - Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), Customer(nvarchar(255))

Table 17 - 17 columns - Circuit ID(nvarchar(255)), Customer(nvarchar(255)), Contact(nvarchar(255))
```

Comment: Could you tell us what your RDBMS is - impossible to give good advice without this. Could you also give us the datatypes of the relevant fields?

Comment: It also seems strange to me that you should keep so many copies of the same data - Circuit_ID appears > 10 times.

Comment: It is MS SQL.  I will look up the datatypes now.  You are absolutely correct, that's the main reason I am working on this.  The dis-organization was absolutely shocking.  Not only does it appear frequently, but, despite having the same name for some of them, they don't necessarily have the same thing.

Comment: Been there, done that. I have also been that guy in the trenches with appalling data appallingly organised. I once had a system that had a table with 35,000 (that's 35k) fields. Best of luck :-)

Comment: At least I like learning and like a challenge.  hahahaha.  Thank you.  I have edited the post to include the data types.

Comment: I have an idea, but for it to work, each table needs a primary key. Does each table have a primary key? Use this to check SELECT TABLE_NAME,column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1

Comment: They don't have primary keys right now, but I can get that setup and I will try it out.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back to you again the other day.  Since I don't have any of the existing fields set as a primary key, would the idea you have work if I just added a column with a numeric value to use as the key instead of setting one of the existing items?

Comment: I have added primary keys to the tables, so each one has an additional column called P_Key

Comment: Out of curiousity - did you ever get something to work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Is the application going to search for these one by one?  Is the performance of this query important?  Easy (ish) solution would be to create a stored procedure that accepted some arguments and then returned the results from searching each table.

Results from the stored procedure could include the table it found a match on, the primary key and the field that matched.  Then the caller of that stored procedure could do more work based on that result set.

EDIT - Below is a very basic sample procedure for you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_FindCircuit
    (
    @Search NVARCHAR(100)
    )
AS
BEGIN

--Hold Results.
DECLARE @Results TABLE
    (
    TableName VARCHAR(100) NULL
    , FieldName VARCHAR(100) NULL
    , KeyValue INT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @Results
        (TableName, FieldName, KeyValue)
SELECT 'Table 5'
    , 'Circuit ID'
    , <PrimaryKey>
FROM [Table 5]
WHERE CircuitID LIKE ('%' + @Search + '%')

--Repeat for each table.


--Return data.
SELECT TableName, FieldName, KeyValue
FROM @Results 

END
```

Comment: I think it will be searching 1 by 1 as I don't know a way around that.  Performance is not important for this as I will only by running it once or twice.  I was thinking a stored procedure would be a good way to go, but I don't have enough knowledge to figure it out.

Comment: I've edited my comment to include a very rough sample for you.

Comment: I apologize for my delayed response.  I will try this out.  That looks promising as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it (the code is in the blog post):

http://selectallfromideas.blogspot.com.au/2014/08/searching-all-columns-in-all-tables-in.html (It's my blog and my code)

It's hardly elegant code, but if you need to find certain data in string type columns in all user tables in a database, this is one way to do it. It will tell you what table the data is in, and give you the query to get that data. I haven't included functionality to automatically put it into another table though, but it isn't difficult to do.

Please be advised though: It CAN take a long time to run depending on the size of your database, because you're asking SQL Server to execute a query that isn't SARGable possibly millions of times. I strongly suggest you run it against a copy of the database on a server that doesn't have high load just in case your database is huge (if you're able to).

Comment: That is definitely over my head.  I will try it out for sure.  Thank you very much.  I can imagine it will take a while, but because of the state of the data and the fact that I

Comment: This definitely looks like it is going down the right path.  I had to change the column names some and make a couple other changes to the data, but for the parts it does run it looks like it is doing exactly what you said it would.  Is it possible to have it return the row and column that it found the match in as well?

Comment: I am running into a couple errors though.  When I run it I get the following:

Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '%17HFGS5'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '%17HFGS5'.
 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.

Below that I see the tables that it ran successfully.  It is not running on the first 2 tables in the database, but the others are running fine.

Comment: An interesting thing about the first and second errors are that they list the search string as '%17HFGS5' which is only part of the string, but on the tables that it runs successfully on it shows it correctly '%17HFGS505152NV%'.  Any idea what I may need to change?

Comment: If you've changed the code at all, I can't really help you with the changes without seeing them. I have updated the code on the blog post to hold a larger search string (you don't need to specify wildcard operator, just in case you were) and handle spaces in column names, which is probably where the syntax error originates from.

Comment: As for getting it to return the rows/columns that it found - the updated version will give you the queries for the rows containing the data, at which point you can copy/paste those into a query window and run it. I couldn't come up with a more custom script though.

Comment: I apologize for my seriously delayed response.  I didn't have to change any of your code, I just modified my data to what would work.  Aside from the errors and not searching the first 2 tables, this works to identify where there are matches.  I am using some of what you had there to try and come up with a more automated process as I have a few thousand id's/strings to search for.  Thank you very much for the help.